Number of isomorphisms between categories
Let $\mathcal{C}_1$ be a category with objects $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6\}$. The number of isomorphisms between them is $3!=6$ and morphisms $27$. Can we extend this notion of number of isomorphisms to number of isomorphisms between categories?
For say, consider another category $\mathcal{C}_2$ with objects $C=\{2,3,4\}$ and $D=\{4,5,6\}$. The number of isomorphisms and morphisms are same as before.
Now consider the functor $F:\mathcal{C}_1\to\mathcal{C}_2$. A possible isomorphic functor could be

I have shown only $3$ morphisms each for brevity. A simple calculation would give $2\times27!$ ways, where the factor $2$ comes from the different morphisms  $A\to C$ and $A\to D$.
This brings the question of considering morphisms from $B\to A$ and $C\to D$ as well, which we ignored in the above calculation (note: this need not be considered if we had only considered the isomorphisms between the objects). This would complicate things, and I imagine the possibilities to be $2\times54!$, which is very large.
I could not find any resources talking about number of isomorphic functors. I would appreciate if someone could verify the correctness of the idea laid out here.

The $27!$ piece is wrong. It is a number of all possible permutations over the set of all morphisms. But not every such permutation results in a valid functor. First of all $F(id)=id$, secondly given $g:A\to B$ our functor has to map $F(g^{-1})=F(g)^{-1}$. Finally $F$ has to respect domain and codomain. This restricts the number of possible functors quite heavily.

@freakish Ah nice catch! I didn't consider endomorphisms at all, where the identity preservation comes. The other conditions hold as a consequence of all morphisms mapping to all other morphisms uniquely. This case is rather simple with not having to worry about compositions.

Note that your description of $C_1$ in the first sentence is not enough to conclude anything about its morphisms: you could very well be talking about the discrete category whose objects are ${1, 2, 3}$ and ${4, 5, 6}$. What you probably intended to say is "let $C_1$ be the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ on the objects ${1, 2, 3}$ and ${4, 5, 6}$". Note that this is equivalent (not isomorphic) to the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ on any three-element set.
